# body.clientHeight/Width too large in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

`document.body.clientHeight` and `document.body.clientWidth` return the wrong size in Firefox, its just slightly too big. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ggka0ddr/) to illustrate the problem. I set an elements width and height equal to the clientWidth and clientHeight which should fill the screen, no more, no less. Works great in Chrome but in Firefox the div is larger than the body (there are scrollbars).

Note: This is an example to illustrate the problem, I am well aware that this could be written using css.

What is causing the incorrect values here? Any way to compensate?

Comment: Did you try adding a [CSS reset](http://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/) ?

Comment: Modified the jsfiddle to include a CSS reset, but it made no difference.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the code and markup given in your jsfiddle. I see no scroll bar in Firefox (in the jsfiddle window or in a test project). Could it be caused by a toolbar or something else in your Firefox configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be an addon I use [Tab Tree](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-tree/), if I disable it everything works as it should.